# Sending a message to a specific contact (my father) fails

Tags: google-hangouts

My question contains various quotes. I will try to translate them from German (the language of my country Germany) to English.

Sending a Hangouts message to my father fails. No matter if I try to send the message via the web interface of Gmail on my laptop (Windows 7) or if I try to send it via the Hangout app my Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo mobile phone, sending a message to my father will fail. When I try to send a message via the web interface of Gmail I get the following error message:

> The message was not delivered

When I try to send a message via the Hangout App on my mobile phone I get the following error message:

> Error while sending, Tap to retry.

I guess the problem is inside of my Google account, because both sending methods fail.

Both sending methods (web interface of Gmail on my Laptop and Hangout App on my mobile phone) succeed, when I try to send a Hangout message to any other contact than my father.

My problem began when I have tried to send a Hangout message on my mobile phone to my father. Sending a Hangout message to my father initially failed due to  mobile data network problem of my provider O2 in Bad Wildungen (my current location). I called the provider and it has fixed its network problem. Ever since the mobile data problem has occurred I am not able to send a Hangout message to my father.

Comment: Didn't we remove your exact same question as being off-topic just yesterday? - Also have you ever considered that this may be a problem on your fathers receiving end rather than your sending end?

Comment: I had left a similar comment to @SleepingGod's on your other question.  I think that's the best thing to try.  (for the record, though, the other question was user-deleted with only 2 close votes)

Comment: I deleted the other question voluntarily. As it turned out, my father has blocked me because I got on his nerves. Now he has unblocked me and I am able to send messages to him again. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @Norbert Willhelm - That may be the best course of action

Comment: Hangouts is a webapp and the “user has blocked you is a possibility” sounds like a possibly useful answer for the case where a message mysteriously fails to be delivered. If you post that you were blocked as an answer, wouldn’t this be a useful contribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP commented that this situation turned out to be a case of the recipient using Hangouts’s “block user” feature.

Many messaging websites will fail to deliver messages to other users with mysterious/inexplicable reasons or silently fail to deliver a message at times. If this happens, it is possible that the recipient has blocked you. To protect users, when a blocked user tries to send a message, the blocked user is not given a very specific error message. Or, perhaps, the recipient is made invisible to the sender or the message is silently failed instead of even showing an error. This is because the block feature is meant to be useful in the situation where the blocked user is harassing another user. Additionally, you may not be able to join any group conversations when any user in that group conversation has blocked you.

**To people who consider using the “block” feature**: the “block” feature is meant for handling users who endlessly harass or spam you who you are unlikely to want to contact again. If a person is annoying you but you intend to maintain a relationship with them, please consider not blocking that person. Many messaging websites offer a “mute notifications” feature. For example, in [Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com/), open a conversation. From there, click the gear icon, and uncheck *Notifications*. Your browser and devices will no longer bug you with messages on that conversation, but you must remember to re-enable *Notifications* for that user later. Or if all Hangouts interactions are troubling you temporarily, open the menu in the upper-left hand corner (☰), choose Settings (gear), and under *Notifications* open the dropdown *Mute notifications for…* and choose a time period. To unblock someone in [Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com), open the menu in the upper-left hand corner (☰), choose Settings (gear), open *Blocked people*, locate the blocked user, and choose *Unblock*.

**To people who end up blocked**: understand that sometimes people use the “block” feature without understanding the ramifications. For example, one might block someone even if they intend to contact them in the future. The “block” feature may cause the person who used it to be confused and unable to find the blocked person. To reduce the chances that another user decides to block you, please be understanding of other users and respect any requests to be quieter. Before sending a message, consider that something which seems important and pressing to you may just be an annoyance to the recipient. Also consider being less “spammy” by, e.g., composing a complete thought when sending a message instead of sending a bunch of short messages (one meaningful notification is less annoying than a series of partial-thought notifications). It is better to behave considerately to avoid being blocked if you want to still be able to contact the other user when something important comes up.

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to send Hangout a message to my father, because he has blocked my Google Account at Google Hangout. He has accidentally discovered that he has blocked my Google Account. Today he has unblocked my Google Account. That's why I have been able to send a Hangout message to him again.